# Why is the performance of those 3 very similar neo4j cypher queries that drastically different?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, database-performance

Any ideas why the first cypher query is extremely faster than the second and third ones?

**First query:**

```
MATCH (source:Product { product_id:14603 }), 
      (destination:Product{product_id:286502}), 
      p = (source-[r]-()-[*0..3]-destination) 
RETURN p, length(p) as pathLength LIMIT 50
```

==> 14 seconds

```
==> 50 rows
==> 
==> |             Operator | Rows | DbHits |                                      Identifiers |                                 Other |
==> +----------------------+------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
==> |         ColumnFilter |   50 |      0 |                                                  |            keep columns p, pathLength |
==> |                Slice |   50 |      0 |                                                  |                          {  AUTOINT2} |
==> |              Extract |   50 |      0 |                                                  |                            pathLength |
==> |          ExtractPath |   50 |      0 |                                                p |                                       |
==> | SimplePatternMatcher |   50 |      0 | source,   UNNAMED90, destination, r,   UNNAMED89 |                                       |
==> |          SchemaIndex |   99 |    198 |                                   source, source |            {  AUTOINT0}; :Product(product_id) |
==> |     TraversalMatcher |   99 | 419669 |                                                  |   UNNAMED89,   UNNAMED90,   UNNAMED89 |
==> +----------------------+------+--------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
==> 
==> Total database accesses: 419867
```

**Second query:**

```
MATCH (source:Product { product_id:14603 }), 
      (destination:Product{product_id:286502}), 
      p = (source-[r]-()-[*0..2]-destination) 
RETURN p, length(p) as pathLength LIMIT 50
```

==> 140 seconds

```
==> 13 rows
==>  
==> +----------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
==> |             Operator |    Rows |  DbHits |                                      Identifiers |                                 Other |
==> +----------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
==> |         ColumnFilter |      13 |       0 |                                                  |            keep columns p, pathLength |
==> |                Slice |      13 |       0 |                                                  |                          {  AUTOINT2} |
==> |              Extract |      13 |       0 |                                                  |                            pathLength |
==> |          ExtractPath |      13 |       0 |                                                p |                                       |
==> | SimplePatternMatcher |      13 |       0 | source,   UNNAMED90, destination, r,   UNNAMED89 |                                       |
==> |          SchemaIndex | 2266560 | 4533120 |                                   source, source |            {  AUTOINT0}; :Product(product_id) |
==> |     TraversalMatcher | 2266560 | 2266605 |                                                  |   UNNAMED89,   UNNAMED90,   UNNAMED89 |
==> +----------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
==> 
==> Total database accesses: 6799725
```

messages.log:

```
2014-11-26 03:41:18.282+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 139ms [total block time: 14.49s]
2014-11-26 03:41:20.086+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 101ms [total block time: 14.591s]
2014-11-26 03:41:29.022+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 144ms [total block time: 14.735s]
2014-11-26 03:41:43.230+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 151ms [total block time: 14.886s]
2014-11-26 03:41:45.160+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 127ms [total block time: 15.013s]
2014-11-26 03:41:48.830+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 135ms [total block time: 15.148s]
2014-11-26 03:42:01.956+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 134ms [total block time: 15.282s]
2014-11-26 03:42:05.731+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 171ms [total block time: 15.453s]
2014-11-26 03:42:07.555+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 122ms [total block time: 15.575s]
2014-11-26 03:42:13.271+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 144ms [total block time: 15.719s]
2014-11-26 03:42:36.465+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 115ms [total block time: 15.834s]
```

**Third query:**

```
MATCH (source:Product { product_id:14603 }), 
      (destination:Product{product_id:286502}), 
      p = (source-[*0..3]-destination)
RETURN p, length(p) as pathLength LIMIT 50
```

==> infinite run time (after 10 minutes maxing out the CPU, I restart the neo4j server)

---

### Server data:

- Neo4J Version: community-2.1.1
- Nodes: 650,000
- Product Nodes: 550,000
- Properties: 8,000,000
- Relationships: 6,000,000
- Relationship types: 9
- 32GB RAM
- 768GB SSD
- 12 Core CPU

**Indexes:**

ON :Product(product_id) ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)
[...] some others not relevant indexes for these queries

**neo4j.properties**

- neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=50M
- neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=400M
- neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=400M
- neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=400M
- neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=400M
- node_cache_size=5G
- relationship_cache_size=5G
- all other properties are default

---

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to match every type of relationship, or could you put a  relationship type constraint in the square brackets `[r:TAGGED]` or `[:TAGGED*0..2]`? (I do not understand why 1 is faster than 2), can you add some detail about your server/Neo4J configuration.

Comment: For this query all relationship types are of interest.
Server is hosted at linode ==> RAM: 32GB, CPU: 12 Cores, HDD: 768GB SSD


Which neo configurations make sense to post?

Comment: conf/neo4j.properties and also messages.log

Comment: Can you add the `PROFILE` output for all 3 queries formatted to your question? That would be super helpful

Comment: And can you try to run Neo4j 2.1.5 ?

Comment: Just added the profile information for the first two queries. Don't want to run the third one now and kill the server. Will try to do so tomorrow.
Going to add conf/neo4j.properties and messages.log tomorrow as well.

@Michael: have to run the import of our data tomorrow to a fresh new installation of 2.1.5. Going to post results as soon as possible.

Comment: @Michael: I run the first and second query on 2.1.5 with the same results. No difference in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any difference if you try putting each of those patterns as a separate MATCH rather than comma separated? e.g.

```
MATCH (source:Product { product_id:14603 })
MATCH  (destination:Product{product_id:286502})
MATCH p = (source-[r]-()-[*0..3]-destination) 
RETURN p, length(p) as pathLength LIMIT 50
```

Also if you run the query at /webadmin then you can try prefixing it with the word 'PROFILE' and paste the output of that on here and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Thx @Mark,

using this query sadly completely maxes out the server. I had to restart neo4j after waiting for 5 minutes.

I run the profile with my original query #1:  

==> ColumnFilter | +Slice | +Extract | +ExtractPath | +SimplePatternMatcher | +SchemaIndex | +TraversalMatcher  
==> Total database accesses: 419867  

ColumnFilter, Slice, Extract, ExtractPath, SimplePatternMatcher had 50 rows each and 0 dbHits.  
SchemaIndex had 99 Rows and 198 DbHits.  ==> TraversalMatcher had 99 rows and 419669 DbHits  
  
The :Product(product_id) index has been used.

Comment: Are you able to share a (maybe anonymised?) version of the dataset so I can play around with it and figure out what's going on?

Comment: Sadly no...
Any other information you might could use? Thx again

Comment: Any way you can add directions to the last pattern?